# Loop an array values while joining them to another array values

Tags: php, arrays, loops, join, foreach

I have two arrays

```
$a = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p');
$b = array('1','2','3','3','4','2','1','4','2','2');
```

Array $a sometimes has more values.

I need to join those two arrays but for result I need to loop values of the array $b as long there are values of the array $a.

Result should be like this

```
a1
b2
c3
d3
e4
f2
g1
h4
i2
j2
k1 // array $b starts to loop here
l2
m3
n3
o4
p2
```

Comment: You should take a look at range().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [modulo (php: `%`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) is awesome for this kind of stuff:

```
$i = 0;
$count = count($b);
foreach($a as $val1){
    echo $val1, $b[$i++ % $count];
    // if you don't want to echo, do something else :)
}
```

As soon as `$i` reaches `$count`, `$i % $count` will start at `0` again.

Comment: Consider the answer accepted. I just need to wait few minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
$result = array();

foreach ($a as $val) {
  if (isset($b[$i])) {
    $result[] = $val.$b[$i++];
  } else {
    $result[] = $val.$b[0];
    $i = 1;
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that works no matter what the lengths or the indexes of the two arrays are:

```
function zip(array $a1, array $a2) {
    $a1 = array_values($a1); // to reindex
    $a2 = array_values($a2); // to reindex

    $count1 = count($a1);
    $count2 = count($a2);

    $results = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < max($count1, $count2); ++$i) {
        $results[] = $a1[$i % $count1].$a2[$i % $count2];
    }

    return $results;
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/oaHK7)**.

Answer (score 0):

This makes `$b` "loop-over" until it's as big as `$a`.

```
<?php
    $a = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p');
    $b = array('1','2','3','3','4','2','1','4','2','2');
    while(count($b) < count($a))
        $b = array_merge($b, array_splice($b, 0, count($a) - count($b)));

    print_r($a);
    print_r($b);
?>
```

- http://codepad.viper-7.com/3SUOP6
- http://codepad.viper-7.com/VvkxH0 (test case where `$b` is really small)

Comment: What if `$a` has 100 items and `$b` has 10 (basically, what if `count($a) / count($b) >= 2`)?

Comment: Only works if `$b` is at least half the size of `$a`: http://codepad.org/Oa3EdqVk

Comment: @Xeon06: Even so it's still not good enough IMHO: a) doesn't work right if arrays are not numerically indexed, b) it will be quite a chore to make it work correctly if you want to also "expand" `$a` when it's shorter (*here* you don't need to, but asymmetrical behavior like that in a function is a bug generator), and c) there's really nothing gained by adding all these duplicate elements: you can still write an one-line loop body without doing this. Just some food for thought -- this is an approach I thought about as well :)

Comment: @Jon indeed, Goldie's solution is the best.